# UnicodeDecodeError Ordinal not in range, while reading line from file

Tags: python-3.x, file, binary, refactoring

I'm running Python3 on Ubuntu (Jessie). And refactoring some code written originally in Python2.7.

I have a UTF-8 Unicode text file...

```
$ file /home/(smip)/hg19.json
/home/(smip)/hg19.json: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

In the old code has ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8
(...snip...)
with open(filename) as fh:
    return json.load(fh)
```

which causes an error upon attempting to open the file...

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 510: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Changing the code to specify utf-8 like so ...

```
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    return json.load(fh)
```

...fixes that error

SO my question are:

1. Shouldn't Python 3 be able to open the unicode file WITHOUT the encoding="utf-8", thanks to the shebang?
2. If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `coding: utf-8` comment is an [encoding declaration](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) for the source code file. The default for Python 3 is UTF-8.
2. The default encoding used by [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is dependent on the [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale).

You could either set `LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8` externally if you want to let the user decide the encoding or explicitly set it to `utf-8` when you open your data.